# Multiple Image based animations within a page view iOS

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, xcode5

I have a page view controller which I would like to display 5 different image based animations on each page when scrolled. I am currently storing images into an array and then animating it. I have changed the colour for each of the 5 images to show the differences when they animate:

Orange Crystal Ball - 60 images
Pink Crystall Ball - 60 images
Red Crystall Ball - 60 images
Black Crystal Ball - 60 images
Yellow Crystal Ball - 60 images

What is the best way of doing this as I feel like having 5 sets of 60 images, all stored in arrays would not be the best way of implementing the different animations? Surely it would use up a lot of memory?

I'm not trying to make an iphone game, I'm just trying to animate different background images on different pages when scrolled.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a sprite for each animation

Comment: is that possible with full screen iphone images which are high definition?

Answer (score 0):

Loading 60 full-screen images into a UIImageView frame animation might well cause an out of memory crash.

You certainly should not load all 5 sets of images at once, since the user can only view one at a time.

Why not turn them into a movie file and display it using a movie view controller? Movies use hardware-accellerated compression to handle a continuous stream of video frames.